# How to use a 2-wire sonar sensor

Tags: microcontroller

I have been tasked with taking a fairly old robot vehicle and upgrading as many systems as possible.  It has an array of 7 sonar sensors that I would like to re-use, but I don't have a good working knowledge of what to do with them.  They have only two wires.  I sort of know the idea behind how they'll work (send a pulse to the sensor, flip a switch somewhere in the wiring(?), get the return signal, figure out time between the ping and the return) but that's where I'm at.  What I would love is something like an example circuit of how to hook this thing up and I can then try to program some tests on a Raspberry Pi or some other cheap device.

What about the circuit it originally had?  You're very correct to ask about it.  It appears to have used a TI TL851CN chip to control the sonar.  I read the data sheet and it wasn't very illuminating to someone of my experience level (student).  Second, the data sheet says it is meant to be paired with a TL852 chip which is nowhere to be found on the original circuit.  So, I'm not really able to figure out what it's doing.

Comment: Have a look here: [How to Wire Up Ultrasonic Transducer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/93458/how-to-wire-up-ultrasonic-transducer)

Comment: That is very useful, but not quite similar enough to be usable I think.  The transducers on the vehicle are not in pairs; one unit must send and also receive.  The circuits shown there are a send circuit/transducer and a receive circuit/transducer.  Still very good for my own learning, but I won't be able to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this device is a better option. It appears to have transmitter and receiver built in together: -

[image]

Details can be found [here](http://www.prowave.com.tw/pdf/sonar.pdf)